# Selenium unable to locate button in email template

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to use Selenium to locate a button in an email template and click it, but no matter what I use (xPath, css_selector) it seems that my code cannot locate the button and keep getting this error.

```
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element:
```

The email is in Mailinator, I am able to access Mailinator and the email body, but when the `click` action is about to perform, my code fails throwing the above error code.

Did anyone ever experienced this issue and can help me to understand what I am doing wrong?
Please if you need more info just let me know. Thank you very much for your time and help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like it's an iframe, if it is, you need to switch first before interaction :

**Code :**

```
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
wait.until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.XPATH, "iframe xpath here")))
```

and then you can interact :

```
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "email field xpath here"))).send_keys('pass some email address')
```

**Imports :**

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

once done, switch to `default content` like this :

```
driver.switch_to.default_content()
```

Comment: You are a life saver. It did work. Thank you so so so so so so much @cruisepandey